# Count number of null rows for ungrouped orders with Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset where **every row is attributed to one product**. As you can see, order_name 1140 is counted twice, because the user purchases 2 products with the order #1140.
I would like to count how many transactions (order_name) does not have a discount code (equal NaN).

```
    order_name  discount_code   
126 #1137           NaN         
127 #1139         Earlybird     
128 #1140           NaN         
129 #1140           NaN         
130 #1141          Tango
```

Incorrect code:
`df['disc_is_null']=np.where(df['discount_code']==np.NaN,1,0)`
returns

````
    order_name  discount_code   disc_is_null
126 #1137           NaN               0
127 #1139         Earlybird           0
128 #1140           NaN               0
129 #1140           NaN               0
130 #1141         Earlybird           0
```
What I expect:
```
    order_name  discount_code   disc_is_null
126 #1137           NaN               1
127 #1139         Earlybird           0
128 #1140           NaN               1
129 #1140           NaN               1
130 #1141          Tango              0
```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html):

```
df['disc_is_null']=np.where(df['discount_code'].isna(),1,0)
```

Or you can convert `True/False`s to `1/0` by [`Series.view`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.view.html) or [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df['disc_is_null']=df['discount_code'].isna().view('i1')
```

---

```
df['disc_is_null']=df['discount_code'].isna().astype('int')
```

If need count only unique values of `order_name` fileld by missing values:

```
mask = ~df.duplicated(['order_name','discount_code']) & df['discount_code'].isna()
print (mask)
126     True
127    False
128     True
129    False
130    False
dtype: bool

df1 = mask.groupby(df['order_name']).sum().reset_index(name='count_uniq_NaN')
print (df1)
  order_name  count_uniq_NaN
0      #1137               1
1      #1139               0
2      #1140               1
3      #1141               0
```

Answer (score 1):

First I created a function that returns 0 if there is a discount code and 1 otherwise. Then I run it for every order so agg is a DataFrame where the index is the `order_name` and the value is 1 if this order does not have discount code and 0 otherwise. In order to count the number of orders that do not have a discount code run `agg.sum()`.

```
def my_func(records):
    if  pd.isnull(records).sum() > 0:
        return 0
    return 1

agg = df.groupby('order_name')['discount_code'].agg(my_func)
```

Answer (score 1):

Only with Pandas:

You can use [Pandas.Series.isna](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html?highlight=isna#pandas.Series.isna) method in order to build a mask, then you can use [Pandas.Series.where](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html?highlight=where#pandas.Series.where), something like this:

```
mask = ~(df['discount_name'].isna())
df['disc_is_null'] = (df['discount_name'].where(cond=mask, other=1) == 1).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
    order_name  discount_name   disc_is_null
0   #1137             NaN             1
1   #1139            Earlybird        0
2   #1140             NaN             1
3   #1140             NaN             1
4   #1141             Tango           0
```

From pandas documentation:

> Where cond is True, keep the original value. Where False, replace with corresponding value from other.